# super keyword in defineProperty

Tags: javascript

We need to extend JavaScript getter and we do it by overriding it by defineProperty

we need to accomplish below thing and it seems super is not available here is there any way to achieve it

```
Object.defineProperty(func.prototype,"prop",{
    get: function(){
          let x=super.prop;
          console.log(x);
          return x;
}
})
```

NB: we cannot assign func.prototype.prop to another any variable as it throw illegal invocation error

Comment: Probably this would help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super
so you could build it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes and extend it (even if its a function). There's sadly no other way around it.